# Force app to run in scaled mode on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I seem to be coming across solutions for the opposite of my problem.

I am building an app **prototype** and don't have time to build out all the scaling cases for the iPhone 6. I'm hoping to be able to make it work well for the iPhone 5 native size, and then for people using the prototype on an iPhone 6, have it just be a scaled view.

But when I run the prototype iOS app in the simulator using iPhone 6, it is running in native iPhone 6 mode. The views are all messed due to AutoLayout constraints.

Is there anyway I can just force the app to run in scaled mode using the iPhone 5 screen layout?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Take a look at the "contentScaleFactor" property on UIView.

Comment: Just delete the "Launch Screen File".